# how to extract data from ID card using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

I have a below image and I am extracting the text from the image.The below image is a template image not a genuine Id.

[image]

I am using the below code to extract the text from the image:

```
def data_extraction_with_cleaning(path,file_name,threshold,preprocess_resize,filtering):
    """This function will do data extraction along with image preprocessing"""
    image = cv2.imread(path+file_name)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # check to see if we should apply thresholding to preprocess the
    # image
    if threshold == "thresh":
        gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
                             cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    
    elif threshold == "adaptive":
        gray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)
   
    if preprocess_resize == "linear":
        gray = cv2.resize(gray, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    
    elif preprocess_resize == "cubic":
        gray = cv2.resize(gray, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    
    # make a check to see if blurring should be done to remove noise, first is default median blurring
    
    
    if filtering == "blur":
        gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
    
    elif filtering == "bilateral":
        gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 9, 75, 75)
    
    elif filtering == "gauss":
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    else:
        pass
    
    # write the grayscale image to disk as a temporary file so we can
    # apply OCR to it
    filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
    cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
    

    # load the image as a PIL/Pillow image, apply OCR, and then delete
    # the temporary file
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang = 'eng')
    text = re.sub(r'[^\da-zA-Z0-9_() \n]+', '', text)
    # text = text.replace('\n', ' ')
    
    # add +hin after eng within the same argument to extract hindi specific text - change encoding to utf-8 while writing
    os.remove(filename)
    # print(text)
    
    # show the output images
    # cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    # cv2.imshow("Output", gray)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    
    # writing extracted data into a text file
    text_output = open('outputbase1.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    text_output.write(text)
    text_output.close()
    
    file = open('outputbase1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    text = file.read()
    # print(text)
    
    # Cleaning all the gibberish text
    text = ftfy.fix_text(text)
    text = ftfy.fix_encoding(text)
    return text

text_passport_can = data_extraction_with_cleaning(path,file_name,'thresh','linear','blur')
```

The output text is coming as junk.Below is my Output file.

```
Qo Authority Awdurdod Ugndarras Instanuey f Aulotay
Myxieghed Udaras Exbou00 Apxt Autondades Ait
Vieanomaineny Myndighel Pus vydall Valpanigal tedgvegagtace Tadaves
Awtorta Organ Whadry Organ Urad Kisaits hatgag 
 dwte of expiry Dydidiad dod i ben Bileachdach gu De gekigheldichar
van dt paspuor eindigt op Date dexpiration Gidtig bis Data di
Kadenza Cykiigt indi As feldhrry Muepounvic Migs Vilido ad Este
pasaporie explra el Varmeinen vounmsssolopiva Gaugt La tn Plytnost
Joy Kehtiy kuni Deriquma teeming Gahop iki Data ta Ightetug Date
Wygaineeda Waznoicy Yel do Odtum platnostif Lefirau 35

  

 PEGBRALEXRGORDIEV 6   6 6 CK CK KKK KK KEK KEE

x

  

1071926378GBR8412036M1 80628702
```

How to deal with such case.I know about one package `PassportEye` which deals with Passport data extraction.But I am looking for data extraction with `OpenCv` or `Pytesseract` as i have other ID's to extract text from.

Comment: Do you have only one image? If you have multiple you can (I guess you know that) try and train a ML to do that. If not, essentially you are looking to use a pre-trained one; is that correct?

Comment: visualize all intermediate steps of your data. you need to see what you're doing.